# Pagination missing after choosing 50 per page

Tags: bug

I was browsing the questions list, and clicked the `50 per page` link, but now it shows all the questions and there are no more buttons to revert to a smaller number!

This is definitely a bug and even after cleaning the cache and cookies I can't get the pagination links back.

How can I get the pagination links back?

UPDATE: now that we have more than 50 questions, the paginations links/buttons are visible again. This is still something that should be investigated.

UPDATE 2: It happens in META as well, and also not working in the top questions of the main site; until both reach above the 50 it will be broken :(

Comment: Probable a bug of not being able to set the questions-to-display per page when there are less question (currently 41) than the amount set to be display (50 in your case and now mine too since I tested it :( ).

Comment: definitely a bug.

Comment: You can get the pagination links back by manually adding `pagesize=15` (or however many you want displayed) to the URL. (Maybe this should be posted on http://meta.stackexchange.com/ if not already?)

Comment: This might be a late answer but if the problem still exists try question lists in the `/questions` page and not in the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

I think that will fix it self if we have more then 50 questions ;-)

Comment: I think so too, but it is still a bug until then (could be a problem for future beta sites) :)